# Good syslog server for Windows

Tags: windows, syslog

I've been trying to find a "good" syslog server to provide centralized application login for a distributed system we've built.  Our application logging system can not only log to files but also to a syslog server and we would like to utilize this feature.  The following would be nice:

- Runs as a Windows service
- Has a reasonably good viewing/searching (via web display ideal)
- Is open source, free, or low cost

There are numerous solutions available on Linux/Unix, but few for Windows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you tried [Kiwi Syslog Server](http://www.kiwisyslog.com/kiwi-syslog-server-overview/)? I used it for quite a while before I started sending everything to a CentOS box...  I'll confess to being a year out of date, but at the time the free version suited my needs.

Comment: Kiwi Syslog server is a great tool

Answer (score 5):

Splunk is free for under 500M of logs per day. It'll cover Windows and Linux and provide you with a very good web interface.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if it falls under your definition of low cost, but I think it does provide a lot of bang for the money.  Look into [Microsoft System Center Operations Manager](http://www.microsoft.com/systemcenter/operationsmanager/en/us/default.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Try this application:

http://www.aonaware.com/

1. It's web-based
2. Stores everyting to SQL Server 2005 Express Edition (use the advanced vers. for generating reports)
3. It's free, (But send the guy some bucks)

Answer (score 1):

[Splunk](http://www.splunk.com/) is very popular.  It listens on the syslog port among other ways of slurping up logs.  It is also a very robust search engine for logs.  We pay about $5k for 2GB of data indexed daily.  If you are under 500MB of logs daily, it is free.

Runs on Windows as well as other UNIX flavors.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.fantail.net.nz/wordpress/?p=5

> C# code for Syslog server is available there; uses SQL Server at backend...very robust/light and scalable...Have been using it for quite some time with no problem what so ever! Best part; source is very neatly written and you can learn some network programming!

Comment: Not found http://www.fantail.net.nz/downloads/FantailSyslogServerSrc.zip