# How can I ship Windows Server 2008 event logs to a syslog server?

Tags: windows-server-2008, service, windows-event-log, syslog

In the past with Windows Server 2003 I was able to ship the event logs to a central network syslog server using evtsys (https://engineering.purdue.edu/ECN/Resources/Documents/UNIX/evtsys). It does not mention support for Server 2008 but does mention problems with sending Windows Vista logs.

Are there any good services/utilities or even PowerShell scripts (preferably one of the other ones as this wouldn't be continuous) that could send the event logs to a central syslog server?

Comment: Not sure if 2008 logs are different enough to warrant a merge, but see also http://serverfault.com/questions/6110/good-syslog-server-for-windows

Comment: @Kara: that question is about syslog servers, this one is about clients to send data to the syslog server. Related, but not the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [Snare for Windows](http://www.intersectalliance.com/projects/SnareWindows/), a free software (freeware), released under the terms of the GNU Public Licence (GPL).

> Snare for Windows Vista is a Windows
>   2008 and Windows Vista compatible
>   service that interacts with the
>   underlying "Crimson" Eventlog
>   subsystem to facilitate remote,
>   real-time transfer of event log
>   information. Snare for Windows Vista
>   also support 64 bit versions of
>   Windows (X64 and IA64).
>
> Event logs from the Security,
>   Application and System logs, as well
>   as the new DNS, File Replication
>   Service, and Active Directory logs are
>   supported. The supported version of
>   the agent also accommodates custom
>   Windows event logs. Log data is
>   converted to text format, and
>   delivered to a remote Snare Server, or
>   to a remote Syslog server with
>   configurable and dynamic facility and
>   priority settings.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: http://www.ashleyknowles.net/2009/10/windows-2003-2008-event-logging-to-syslog/