# Is centralized logging a good idea?

Tags: logging, syslog

Right now, my organization has a solution comprised of 10+ components, and some have a log file per thread. Since files are rotated hourly, tracking all of this is a chore.

Is centralizing all logging to a specific machine (using rsyslog or something similar) a good idea? Wouldn't I be trading simplicity for hecticness? Are there good log viewers for this high volume use case?

We're a straight up Microsoft shop, by the way.

Thanks for any replies!

Comment: See http://serverfault.com/questions/6110/good-syslog-server-for-windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you take a look at [Splunk](http://www.splunk.com).

I currently have it in production, with 30+ network devices logging to it--It is really useful to have logs in one place, that I can write my own queries for, run canned reports, etc.

Comment: It's bloody expensive though, especially when you get up to >5GB/day of data.

Comment: @ Tom: Definitely.

Comment: just how expensive?

Comment: @sardaukar jaw dropping, are you f'in kidding me expensive

Comment: @sardaukar Last pricing I got for 5GB/day was $32,000, and about $10,000 a year for support

Answer (score 6):

One BIG advantage of centralized logging is this:

- If one of your machines is ever compromised, *and the logs altered to hide that fact*, you will still have an un-tampered copy on your central logging server.

Another is:

- In my case I also have a dedicated monitor at my workstation running off of the central logging server that displays any logs of a priority "Warning" or higher in real time, so that I can deal with any problems immediately as they come up. (hopefully before the end-user notices :) ).  This is difficult to do without a centralized server.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at eventsentry as well, not very expensive for few licenses, can setup good filters and alerting etc.

Answer (score 1):

Centralized logging is always a good idea, provided your log server is in a secured location.

Have you looked at Splunk and/or Spiceworks?

www.splunk.com
www.spiceworks.com

Comment: Spiceworks is not a logging app, so I am not sure what it would do for the OP(?)

Comment: Spiceworks does have some basic log charting and checking features (http://community.spiceworks.com/help/Windows_Event_Logs) but nothing like dedicated log management software.  Splunk is a good choice.

Comment: I suggested both, because I use them together to monitor both my local and hosted environments.

Answer (score 1):

Our AD DC security logs go through between 3-5GB of logs a day during busy times, and there is just no way on this Earth to do anything with them via native tools. Some kind of log-parser is needed to make sense of them. I wrote one from scratch in PowerShell, and we've recently looked at Splunk. Splunk can keep up to the deluge and also keep up with our net-device syslog data (almost as big volume wise). All in one database. It'll take a beefy server to chew through that kind of data load, but that's a solvable problem. We're currently waiting on the right Dark Rites to complete so we can get funding for a centralized logging environment.

Having a "single pane of glass" as a view into the data is a good thing. What you won't get is an updating text-file you can then tail syslog-style. What you will get is an interface with a rich query system, and (I believe) an API for writing your own web front-ends for your own nefarious needs.

When it comes to Windows Event-log data, Splunk is not pulling out the XML version of those events, it's pulling out the "detailed view" text version of each event and parsing that. I had some real worries about scale there, but I was pleasantly surprised when it managed to keep up to our logging loads in spite of that; I had to go XML with my PowerShell script because text-parsing was taking w-a-y too long.